# Selenium: Is there any build automation tool like "Maven" for .net where we can define dependencies, plugins, test suite etc

Tags: java, c#, .net, selenium, jenkins

Previously, I automated web applications using Java - selenium, testng /junit, Maven, Jenkins. Now I need to shift from Java to .Net environment due to company requirements.

> Is there any build automation tool like Maven for .net?

Answer (score 1):

There are many tools recommended are

1) NUBuild 
http://nubuild.codeplex.com/

2) BuildIt
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817671.aspx

3)NuGet
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/what-is-nuget

4) MSbuild
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild

Many more are listed here , you can choose according to your requirement.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/).

From their official documenation:

> An essential tool for any modern development platform is a mechanism
>   through which developers can create, share, and consume useful
>   libraries of code. Such libraries are typically referred to as
>   "packages" because they can contain compiled code (as DLLs) along with
>   other content that might be needed in the projects that consume those
>   libraries. For .NET, the mechanism for sharing code is NuGet, which
>   defines how packages for .NET are created, hosted, and consumed, and
>   provides the tools for each of those roles.

Answer (score 0):

[**NuGet**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package) is the most commonly used tool for automation with selenium and C#. I would recommend this.
If for some reason NuGet doesn't get you what you want, try these as stated in a previous answer.

[**MSBuild**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd393574.aspx) - Very good integration with the Microsoft Visual Studio package.

[**BuildIt**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817671.aspx) - Another lightweight Microsoft alternative, I wouldn't really recommend it for novice users.

> Also read [***NuGet is fully integrated into MSBuild***](https://blog.nuget.org/20170316/NuGet-now-fully-integrated-into-MSBuild.html), you could
>   do it this way if you prefer the ease/flexibility provided with
>   MSBuild and the convenience of NuGet